# Email verification for sign in on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, frontend

I want to make a component for registration with verification email on a site using firebase on React.
I have an error Help please how to cope.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W12FP.png)

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail is not a function

[[image: Code for FirebaseCode for Registartion]

Comment: show us how do you import the fun

Comment: Yes, it looks like you haven't imported that auth module in your Webpack config.

Comment: You can look at the images. I added an image of my code

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, links and images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed query bracket and and try again 
auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, config);